Loading MATLAB data in Python with h5py causes permuted dimensions
I'm using the following code to load a MATLAB file into Python
import h5py
import numpy as np
filepath = 'file.mat'
arrays = {}
f = h5py.File(filepath)
for k, v in f.items():
    arrays[k] = np.array(v)

a=arrays['data']

a.shape

Where in MATLAB my data has the following size:
>> size(dataset)

ans =

    64    50    21     2

While in Python
>>> a.shape
(2, 21, 50, 64)

Why are my dimensions permuted backwards and how can I fix this?

MATLAB leading dimensions are inner most, so called Fortran order. numpy defaults to C order, trailing dimensions inner most, though it can use F.  I think the switch actually occurs when MATLAB writes to HDF5. loadmat, reading the native MATLAB file loads order F arrays into numpy.

If the answer helped you out, would you mind, please, accepting it as correct?

MATLAB has Fortran roots.  HDF5 is C++; h5py uses cython to interface.

So... is it even possible to import this Matlab data to Python?

I gave up on h5py. I went back to Matlab, saved the data with '-v7', and then loaded it to Python with scipy loadmat - this worked perfectly.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/export-to-hdf5-files.html#bqyqs27 says that low level HDF5 interface routines use row-major indexing.  So h5py is loading the dimensions as MATLAB wrote them.

The reversal happens because of the different ways MATLAB and Python(NumPy) store data in memory.
Modified code that correctly transposes dimensions:
import h5py
import numpy as np
filepath = 'file.mat'
arrays = {}
f = h5py.File(filepath, 'r')
for k, v in f.items():
    arrays[k] = np.array(v)
a = arrays['data']
a = np.transpose(a, axes=(3, 2, 1, 0))
print(a.shape)


Thanks. I'm still trying to figure out why its not working tbh. The dimensions are OK, but the data is different (compared to the original in Matlab)...

I guess I gave up. I went back to Matlab, saved the data with '-v7', and then loaded it to Python with scipy loadmat - this worked perfectly.
